# Can you get to South West Rocks by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, australia, diving, new-south-wales

I'd like to dive the apparently amazing [Fish Rock Cave](http://fishrock.com.au/dive/dive-sites/fish-rock-cave) in northern NSW. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=0h4celYPxjg) should give an idea of what the fuss is about - who wouldn't want to swim *through* an island with all those fish and sharks about!

One slight snag is that all the dives centres covering Fish Rock Cave are based in South West Rocks, which isn't on the Sydney-Brisbane railway line, and is on a peninsula away from the main road.

Is it possible to get to South West Rocks by public transport? Perhaps a bus from somewhere like Kempsey station (I'm planning to [take the train again](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3596/places-to-stop-off-along-the-sydney-to-brisbane-railway)). Or do any of the hostels / dive centres do pick ups from the train?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

South West Rocks (and Arakoon) is indeed an amazing place - I was lucky enough to grow up near-by, and holidayed at "the rocks" at least once a year.

The nearest major city to South West Rocks is Kempsey, which is on both the Sydney-Brisbane rail line, as well as on the main highway between those cities.

There are 2 bus services that run multiple daily services between Kempsey and South West Rocks, although keep in mind that at least some of these services double as school buses so you may want to avoid those particular services.

[Busways route 350](http://www.busways.com.au/travelling_with_us/route/350/route-350-kempsey-frederickton-smithtown-south-west-rocks)

[Cavanaghs route 12](http://www.cavanaghs.com.au/cavanaghs/SWR.html) (Timetable may or may not be current!)

The Busways route starts on Belgrave St, but not at the end where the train station is, but instead down near the highway. This is where most of the long distance coaches stop.

Answer (score 3):

According to [lonelyplanet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/australia/new-south-wales/south-west-rocks-and-around/transport/getting-there-away) about getting there & away to/from 
South West Rocks:

> Cavanaghs (6562 7800) does two runs daily to and from Kempsey, leaving from the town bus stop at Horseshoe Bay.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for divers - [South West Rocks Dive Centre collect from Kempsey](http://www.southwestrocksdive.com.au/about/location) and drop you back again, for free, if you're going to be diving with them. I've checked with them by email, and they said they're very happy to collect you from CountryLink trains or long distance buses, and take you back, as long as you give them a bit of notice once you have confirmed travel plans.

As well as diving and transport to/from Kempsey, they have [accommodation too](http://www.southwestrocksdive.com.au/accommodation), so that's looking like a winner for me!